# Rails 3 routes - URL name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm not sure how to change a route's URL. As the `:as` parameter does something else now than in Rails 2

This only changes the route helpers to `faq_path`, but the url still goes to `/faqs`. I want the url to be singular.

```
resources :faqs, :as => "faq" do
  collection { post :sort }
end
```

Doing a single match (below) won't really be the same

```
match "/faq" => "faqs#index"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want change all the URLs related to the faqs resources you can do the following:

```
resources :faqs, :path => 'faq'
```

See [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#translated-paths) for further information.